# Retrieve user details from Active Directory from within an ASP MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have an MVC 5 intranet application set up with windows authentication. I am new to Active Directory. How do I query Active Directory from within my MVC application to retrieve the currently authenticated users details such as email add, telephone etc - so basically with windows authentication all I have is the username?

Some code would help i.e connecting to AD etc?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the `username`, you can query `Active Directory` and grab the necessary information you need for the user. Here's a simple call to `AD` using `AccountManagement` namespace.

```
...
string UserName = "yourUserName";
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com")
{
   using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName)
   if (user != null)
   {
      //user will contain information such as name, email, phone etc..
   }
}
```

Comment: do I need a username password to query active directory?

Comment: It depends on how your application is running. If you have it running in IIS under certain user and that user have access to AD than you don't need to specify username and password. However, let's say you are connecting to some remote AD server from your dev machine, then you need to specify username and password if your username doesn't have access.

Comment: your example does not show how to verify the password.

Comment: ctx.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate) ... incase anyone needs it

Comment: @Mike , the reason it doesn't show how authenticate is because the question didn't asked for that. Question specifies for "authenticated" users.